# SqLite Error in Javafx

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

I have a problem with updating my database after calling a method to sum a new credit balance.

[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "'18.0'": syntax error)

This is my query :

```
try {
        String query = "UPDATE cards SET cardBalance '"+newCreditBalance+"' WHERE cardID = idList.getValue().toString";
        PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
```

Did I make any mistake with '"+newCreditBalance+"'? It should be a double value in both java and my database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax error is because you're missing an equals sign: `"UPDATE cards SET cardBalance="+newCreditBalance`.

However, it's a very bad idea to use string concatenation like that to put values into an SQL query or statement (because of the danger of [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). Instead, pass a string like this to prepareStatement(): `UPDATE cards SET cardBalance = ? WHERE cardID = ?"`

And then call the relevant setter methods before actually executing the query:

```
pst.setFloat(1, newCreditBalance);
pst.setString(2, idList.getValue().toString);
```

You should also be using the correct type for `idList.getValue()`, but from your example I don't know what that should be.

Comment: Also note there is another syntax error since `idList.getValue().toString` is not valid SQL.